# how to generate pdf of a content without using iTextG or iTextSharp in android. Or is it possible?

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I need to generate pdf of the content. Content includes only textviews and texts.I just need a correct way to implement this feature. should I use iTexts or is their any other way.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Android print framework (see the training document [Printing Content](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html)), the user has the option of saving the output to a pdf file. You don't need to do anything special in your application to create pdf output, other than generate the page content using the framework API as described in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, it worked... but how can i setcontent view of recyclerview? I'm getting pdf generated for first item and visible items in the view. @TedHopp

Comment: @rashmi - So only the first row of the recyclerview is showing in the print job? That sounds exactly like [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817295/recycler-view-not-printing-given-data) (which, unfortunately, has no answer at the moment). I'm not sure how to fix that. Let me poke around and if I find anything, I'll let you know.